# How to move label text to top of the input text field only when I type some text

Tags: flutter

I want to move the label text to top of the input text field only when I enter some text. Currently it is moving on top when input text field is getting focus.

```
Widget nameField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: false,
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      controller: nameTextEditingController,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
        labelText: Strings.user_info_page_name_placeholder,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this. Trick here is to use `hintText:`

**First:** using `onChanged:` method.

Code:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => new _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TextEditingController nameTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String _labelText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   // nameTextEditingController.addListener(_hasStartedTyping);
  }

//  void _hasStartedTyping() {
//    setState(() {
//      if (nameTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
//        _labelText = 'Name';
//      } else {
//        _labelText = null;
//      }
//    });
//  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                autofocus: false,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                onChanged: (v){
                  setState(() {
                    if(v.isNotEmpty){
                      _labelText = 'Name';
                    }else{
                      _labelText = null;
                    }
                  });

                },
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: nameTextEditingController,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  labelText: _labelText,
                  hintText: 'Name',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**Second:** using `TextEditingController.addListener()` method.

Code:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => new _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TextEditingController nameTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String _labelText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    nameTextEditingController.addListener(_hasStartedTyping);
  }

  void _hasStartedTyping() {
    setState(() {
      if (nameTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        _labelText = 'Name';
      } else {
        _labelText = null;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                autofocus: false,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
//                onChanged: (v){
//                  setState(() {
//                    if(v.isNotEmpty){
//                      _labelText = 'Name';
//                    }else{
//                      _labelText = null;
//                    }
//                  });
//
//                },
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: nameTextEditingController,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  labelText: _labelText,
                  hintText: 'Name',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: this works fine but we lost the animation here. Can we do something for the animation.

Comment: for this shortcut - unfortunately no - for animation, you have to create your own TextFormField from the source. - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart   @NishantSingh

Answer (score 11):

*Know this was asked some time ago and the given answer probably worked for the time, but since this is the first hit on Google I'll add this  more up-to-date answer*

`InputDecoration` has [floatingLabelBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/floatingLabelBehavior.html) property.

So adding `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto` to your `InputDecoration` would do what you want.

So:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Click me",
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Usese UnderlineInputBorder instead of OutlineInputBorder. The animation will be preserved as well. Found the solution in this [discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63317).

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              ),
              labelText: 'Enter Text',
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white),
        ),
```